# JavasScript function undefined

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, object-expected

i've got an html element declared as so:

```
<div id="taskImage" runat="server">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchViews('div<%# Eval("proId") %>', 'one');">
      <img id='imgdiv<%# Eval("proId") %>' alt="Click to show/hide tasks" border="0" src="..."/>
   </a>
</div>
```

and the javascript function switchViews is declared post-html as such:

```
function switchViews(obj, row) {

      var div = document.getElementById(obj);
    var img = document.getElementById('img' + obj);

    if (div.style.display == "none") {
        div.style.display = "inline";

        img.src = "../../images/icons/delete.png";

    }
    else {
        div.style.display = "none";

        img.src = "../../images/icons/add.png";

    }

}
```

when I click on the html element, i get thrown a JS error saying "Object Exepcted", and in the google chrome script debugger it says that switchViews is undefined.  Why would it think that switchViews is undefined and how would I go about fixing it?  For the record I have tried it with the javascript declared before the html and with the switchViews call in the href attribute but it all ends the same.

**EDIT :** to clear something up, by post-html and pre-html i mean before and after i write out the html elements.  so post would be like

```
<div>
   <!-- All my html stuff -->
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   <!-- All my Javascript -->
</script>
```

and pre would be the reverse of that

Comment: Post Html ? under script tag isn't it?

Comment: What do you meen by "post-html" and "before the html"? Your JS should go in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: yes, it's between script tags. and by post html i mean after all the html elements are declared i have the script tags and all my java script between those tags

Comment: Is `switchViews` nested in another function, or is it declared globally?

Comment: It isn't nested in any other functions, just declared inside of some `<script>` tags, if that's what you mean by globally (sorry, my html knowledge isn't that high)

Comment: @user2216177 What I mean is if it's declared like `function mainFunction () { function switchViews() { } }`, then it won't be accessible outside of `mainFunction`'s scope

Comment: @Ian then no, it isn't declared like that so it _should_ be accessible

Comment: Why you have extra bracket at the end! -- its for some other function?

Comment: @user1848739 sorry, my bad, there's an if check in the function and I missed a bracket

Comment: Without seeing your full page structure and/or your javascript code, it is pretty tough for us to tell you what the problem is. Chances are good that there is an error in your javascript code or in your naming structures. I have updated my answer below with some general debugging tips for js development. Hopefully that will help you track down the issue.

Comment: Do you mind posting your all code? Because your code is working perfectly fine for me! I have gridview and inside itemtemplate I place your html code and it worked! Please share some more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Question

At the point where `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchViews(... etc` is encountered by the browser, does the *function* `switchViews` exist or is it *undefined*?

### Answer

The code defining `switchViews` appears after, so at that time `switchViews` is *undefined*.

### Solution

Place your `<script>` before the rest of the *HTML* or attach the event listener in your *JavaScript* instead of inline. This can be done via [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener) or using *jQuery* and may require you to loop over your *HTMLElements* of interest.

Comment: I had tried it with the `<script>` tag before the rest of the html, but that didn't result in anything different.  How would I go about attaching the event listener via javascript instead of inline as you suggest?

Comment: If placing the `<script>` first didn't resolve the problem, check that another error is not preventing script execution. To add the listeners by _JavaScript_, give the elements you want some class you can use to get them easily and some other attribute for the proId (i.e. _data-proid=""_), then get all elements with that class, loop over them and use `addEventListener` or _jQuery_'s [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as I said above

Comment: To confirm whether `switchViews` is being defined at all, you could attempt calling it from your browser's console.

Comment: That doesn't matter, since the `click` event doesn't happen when the element is rendered...it happens when it's clicked. When it's being rendered, it doesn't check for something like that. This scenario is basically the same as `var a = function () { nonexistentFunction(); };` - the code will fail when `a` is called, not during compilation

Comment: @Ian, you're right ( http://fiddle.jshell.net/sJHze/3/ , see console ). Inline JavaScript always throws me.

Comment: @user2216177 `when I click on the html element, i get thrown a JS error saying "Object Exepcted"` Are you sure that the `"Object Exepcted"` error happens only **after** the click, and is not an error left over from before it? Now Ian has corrected me, this is an entirely different problem; most likely a SyntaxError. i.e. when I said `check that another error is not preventing script execution`

Comment: if this code was part of some sort of form, let's call it BuggedForm, and this form was being called onto a different page, let's call it MasterPage, so MasterPage has a BuggedForm, if something was wrong on MasterPage would it cause the compiler to not compile the javascript on BuggedForm?  I'm trying my best to explain what I'm trying to get at without knowing all the proper terminology for HTML, so sorry if it's confusing

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript should not be declared outside of the HTML tags. It needs to be declared inside a `<script>...</script>` block, and that block should be placed inside the `<html>...</html>` block, typically inside the `<head>`

So the overall structure should be something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
       //your JavaScript goes here
    </script>
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

There are other variations that are valid too, but they will all require everything to be inside the overall `<html>` tag.

If that is satisfied, then you are almost certainly running into an issue with either having an error in your javascript code (if the browser can't parse the function, then it stays undefined) or you have a naming conflict (if you have multiple functions set to the same name or if your function has the same name as an id of one of your html elements, then it will often result in an undefined error).

You will have to check for naming conflicts yourself, but you can confirm whether or not it is a javascript error by commenting out all of your code and replacing it with something like: `alert("this works");`

You could then add your code back in one line at a time until the alert fails to fire (making sure to always have matching parens/brackets, of course). When it fails, you will have found the error.

Comment: Why are you bringing this up? They explained that the `<script>` is just at the end of the `<body>`'s content. It's fine to go in either the `<head>` or the `<body>`

Comment: @Ian I'm answering on an iPad, so I didn't see their updates until after I typed my answer. Edited now to reflect the other likely situations (naming conflicts or js errors)

Comment: Ahh okay, just wanted to let you know and make sure :)

Comment: triple checking my file, it doesn't seem like there's any coding errors or same-named functions/ids in the file.  I'm not sure if it matters, but the html div that has the function call is a part of a `<asp:TemplateField>` for a `<asp:GridView>`.  I'm not sure how common it is to use the asp library but it seems to be the only reason why this stuff wouldn't work.  I've also gone and included the contents of switchViews to show that theres no coding errors in there.